# Rational Team Concert for resource scheduling

Tags: tools, scheduling, resource-planning, task-management

We are evaluating RTC as a primary project management / development framework tool.

In particular we follow a high number of concurrent projects with mutable teams. Our main problem are that we need:

- To obtain a clear view of resource availability, resource scheduling, task estimated time at completion.
- Be able to share the tool with other teams.

How can I use this solution for task/resource scheduling in this manner?

Comment: H Giorgio, I edited your question to make it sound less like a product recommendation question, which would be closed as not constructive and not a good fit for our network. [Q&A is Hard. Let's go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/). Sometimes just very subtle wording can be the difference. If I missed anything or you think you lost the spirit of your question, please feel free to edit it further to add more details. Welcome to PMSE!

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest to contact IBM's Rational product team support if you haven't done so. Since you are paying for the tool, it would be wise to reach them for best partices, guidance, etc.

Comment: Most sales people have an automatic reflex answer to feature queries: Of course..

Comment: I wouldn't buy that. What I would ask is for specific setup & examples. If they are unable to provide that, then you'll need to focus into the community, like he's doing, or look for alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @GastónAlgaze . We contacted the official support and we also had some very useful hands-on sessions. The fact is that those sources could be kind of biased, so I'm trying to get some real world reports to have a broader look.